# Grep Regex Not Behaving as Expected

Tags: regex, grep

I have the following file:

```
this:that
thisthat
this that
this:
:that
aa:bb
13a:59b
a4:b6
thisentryistoolongtomatchthepattern:1234567abcderfslsfl
4df)#(*:049
```

I would like to match only these entries:

```
this:that
aa:bb
13a:59b
a4:b6
```

I am trying to grep out just the entries containing [less than 10 alphanumeric characters]:[less than 10 alphanumeric characters]. I tried the following expression: `^[A-z0-9]{0,10}:[A-z0-9]{0,10}$`. However, this does not match anything. Is there something in this expression not supported by grep?

Comment: Regardless of the specific dialect grep uses, I think you want `^[A-z0-9]{1,10}:[A-z0-9]{1,10}$` unless you want `this:` and `:that` to match.

Comment: So you want those lines whose alpha numeric chars count is <=10? Why then `:that` is not matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]\{1,10\}:[A-Za-z0-9]\{1,10\}$
```

- You'll want to [escape the braces](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), otherwise they'll match actual braces. **This is why you got nothing.**
- As I noted in my comment, I assume you want at least one character on either side of the colon, so I adjusted accordingly.
- To avoid matching non-alphanumerical characters that live between `Z` and `a`, I changed the definition of the character class.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
grep -P '^[A-z0-9]{0,10}:[A-z0-9]{0,10}$' in.txt
```

**output:**

```
this:that
this:
:that
aa:bb
13a:59b
a4:b6
```

If you don't want `this:` nor `:that`, change `{0,10}` to `{1,10}`.

Also, you should use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` instead of `[A-z0-9]`

Comment: I'd recommend adding the modified expression (using [a-zA-Z0-9]) in your answer. Or another option would be specifying the -i option to grep and using [A-Z\d].

Answer (score 1):

just modified your regex a bit, hope this helps

```
\b[A-z0-9]{1,10}:[A-z0-9]{1,10}/g
```

according to your regex `^` will assume position at start of your matching string i.e. before "this:that" and `$` will take a position at the end of the whole string i.e. after `4df)#(*:049`

http://regex101.com/r/rN7hQ2

Answer (score 0):

Just use `grep -E` and I would replace the ranges with `[[:alnum:]]`, so you cannot run into trouble because of locale. Also I think you would be looking for `1,` instead of `0,`

```
grep -E '^[[:alnum:]]{1,10}:[[:alnum:]]{1,10}$' file
```

or

```
grep '^[[:alnum:]]\{1,10\}:[[:alnum:]]\{1,10\}$' file
```